# Get Value From JS

Tags: php, phpjs

i wanna ask, how to get specific value from printed html ? example im grabbing website and load html with DOM, i need get value from js

```
video_bal=videojs('video-player');
video_bal.src(window.atob('base64'));
video_bal.play();
```

im need grabbing value from this **video_bal.src(window.atob** and how to write code in php to get value ?

Comment: You cannot read from php the generated html. You can allways use an ajax call

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Comment: you can find 1000s of ajax tutorials online, if you're not familiar with it. You don't need us to repeat it all here. I suggest studying the more modern fetch() API, rather than the legacy XmlHttpRequest, or anything which requires an extra library.